# How to get RMSEA, CFI of blavaan object in r?

Tags: r, bayesian, structural-equation-modeling

I have a blavaan object such that

```
fit <- blavaan(semmodel, data, prior)
```

how to get BCFI and BRMSEA of fit??

I can get

```
>>fitMeasures(fit)

  npar       logl        ppp        bic        dic      p_dic       waic     p_waic    se_waic      looic 
40.000  -1180.071      0.000   2539.688   2424.244     32.051   2452.604     55.668    104.197   2454.368 
 p_loo     se_loo margloglik 
56.551    104.638  -1296.886
```

these kind of things. but i need to get cfi and rmsea..
plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the BRMSEA and the BCFI.
You must fit the null model:

Example:

```r
## Not run: 
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '
## fit target model
fit1 <- bcfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, cp = "fa",
             n.chains = 2, burnin = 1000, sample = 1000)

## fit null model to calculate CFI, TLI, and NFI
null.model <- c(paste0("x", 1:9, " ~~ x", 1:9), paste0("x", 1:9, " ~ 1"))
fit0 <- bcfa(null.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, cp = "fa",
             n.chains = 2, burnin = 1000, sample = 1000)

## The default method mimics fit indices derived from ML estimation
blavFitIndices(fit1, baseline.model = fit0)

Warning messages:
1: 
10 (3.3%) p_waic estimates greater than 0.4. We recommend trying loo instead. 
2: 
3 (1.0%) p_waic estimates greater than 0.4. We recommend trying loo instead. 

Posterior mean (EAP) of devm-based fit indices:

      BRMSEA    BGammaHat adjBGammaHat          BMc         BCFI         BTLI         BNFI 
       0.098        0.957        0.890        0.903        0.930        0.884        0.910
```